# How to Not Show posts on Category page?

Tags: functions

i simply dont want to show posts on category page and show the description only, i tried this code but it wont work if i use the zero value, 1+ value would work but not 0

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_in_category');
function posts_in_category($query){
    if ($query->is_category) {
        if (is_category('')) {
            $query->set('posts_per_archive_page', 0);
        }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change `is_category('')` to `is_category()`? Alternatively you can use `is_category('category-slug')` to hide posts in a single category.

Comment: yeah but it still showing posts, i just want to show the description and completely remove all post list below it

Comment: Can you change `$query->is_category` to `$query->is_category()`?